# ¿Poner la codificación en un documento HTML usando http-equiv es obsoleto? ¿Cuál es la práctica recomendada y a partir de qué versión de HTML?

Tags: html, buenas-prácticas

Generalmente cuando escribo documentos HTML suelo colocar la codificación así:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Pero en un artículo de [sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/meta-tags-html-basics-best-practices/) dicen lo siguiente:

> ## Obsolete Usage
>
> The meta tag usage has evolved over the years and there are certain
>   popular practices from years ago that should not be followed today.
>   For instance:
>
> ```
> <!-- don't use this! -->
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
> ```
>
> That’s the longer version of the character encoding that was common in
>   XHTML.

O sea:

> ## Uso obsoleto
>
> El uso de etiquetas `meta` ha evolucionado a lo largo de los años y hay ciertas prácticas populares de años atrás que no deben
>   seguirse hoy. Por ejemplo:
>
> ```
> <!-- no utilice esto! -->
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
> ```
>
> Esa es la versión más larga de la codificación de caracteres que era
>   común en XHTML.

**¿Desde qué versión de HTML se considera obsoleto y cuál sería entonces el uso recomendado?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **¿Desde qué versión de HTML se considera obsoleto?**

Desde [`HTML5`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20100624/meta.http-equiv.content-language.html).

> **¿Cuál sería entonces el uso recomendado?**

El equivalente de:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

sería:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Mi titulo</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
   ... 
</body> 
</html>
```

[+ info - MetaCharsetAttribute.wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/doctype-mirror/wikis/MetaCharsetAttribute.wiki)